# Mediawiki 1.39.1 issue with upload size

Tags: mediawiki

All,

I just moved Mediawiki from a hosting provider installation on my own server (local installation). So far it is working, but I have smaller issues like the upload size of files.

By checking in the web I found out that size limits are configured at the php.ini file (+ LocalSettings.php) and the variables for it are (which I would like to set to 2048 MB like below):

```
post_max_size = 2048M
upload_max_filesize = 2048M
```

After I configured that I restarted my apache2, but still at the Mediawiki upload page 8 M is shows as the limit and if i try to upload a file which is a bit over 10 MB I get an advice that it is to big. Additional I would like to add that I set in the Mediawiki config file LocalSettings.php the variable:

```
$wgMaxUploadSize = 2147483648;
```

But still no change!

Maybe someone has an idea about this issue?

Thanks and regards

wolpi

Comment: It sounds like you did everything right. Are you sure you're editing the correct php.ini file? 

Comment: Thanks Adam for your comment! I choosed the php.ini, which is used by the default PHP installation (to find it I got too by checking with search engines): `root@mozart : ~ > php --ini | head
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
...
root@mozart : ~ >`

Answer (score 0):

My idea was to add as a simple comment, but I do not have enough points yet :-)
Have a look here : https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuring_file_uploads for some other suggestions.
Also Adam's suggestion might be a thing. If you use WAMP or MAMP you might have more than one ini files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found my described solution/settings exactly at the link which you posted, but still it don't work ;-) What I forgot to describe is, that I have a Debian system, find below some informations of my system: `root@mozart : ~ > cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian ...
root@mozart : ~ >` My LAMP system contain "MariaDB 10.5.18" and "Apache2 2.4.54-1"